# Hebrew vowels not rendering correctly on web page.

Tags: browser, localization, fonts, hebrew

Sample web page:  http://hebrewresources.com/html5problems/buttonText.html

The letters are okay but the vowels (niqudot) under them are not aligned properly at all.

Happens in both Firefox and the default browser on my EVO running Android 2.3.5.

Sample page looks fine on Firefox for Windows and iPhone browser.

Comment: Android doesn't fully support Hebrew, to my knowledge. Is [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9984&q=hebrew&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) similar to what you're seeing?

Comment: Sounds about the same, thanks. I thought maybe it was a browser problem; that maybe a different browser might avoid the problem.